# Unity catalog on azure databricks external table upgrade fails with below error

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

Is anyone came across below issue during unity catalog table upgrade

1. we have configured unity catalog in azure and assigned one workspace
2. added external location and credentials in unity catalog
3. Assigned create permission on external location
4. Metastore created is using Azure Gen2
5. Location assigned in abfss path and connection test looks good

when we try to upgrade one table we are getting below error

[UPGRADE_NOT_SUPPORTED.UNSUPPORTED_FILE_SCHEME] Table is not eligible for upgrade from Hive Metastore to Unity Catalog. Reason: Unsupported file system scheme wasbs.

I am not seeing any issue in terms of unity catalog, do we have any pre-requisites on source /mnt, as it uses wasbs.  usually it should not consider that as we are upgrading our external table using external credential that was configured

do we need to convert existing mount to abfss format before starting unity catalog external table upgrade, i am not seeing any reason

we have tried to updated table properties and tested pre-requistes

Comment: were you able to fix this issue, can you please add comment on how you resolved it. thanks